# aegis-dss-tools and aegis-manifest-dev : where?

Tags: meego-harmattan, aegis

I'm trying to write a little python application, and to start i simply drop the .py into the device and execute from there.
Now I am at the point where i probably need some credentials for accessing the tracker.

I dont want to create an aegis manifest at this point, since im still in early development, or in the worst case i would like to create a flying manifest for my script and thats it.

I found out (actually in the nokia sdk docs) that what i need is something called aegis-su (in aegis-dss-tools) or aegis-manifest (for the worst case), from aegis-manifest-dev

problem: i searched all google, and i cannot find these packages anywhere..

can someone help me?